# Flutter floor database: The select * query that returns a stream is not updated upon deleting a record

Tags: flutter

Using the floor package for flutter:
https://pub.dev/packages/floor

When trying to delete a record from a table ex."Car" using the below SQL statement, the record is deleted but the reactive stream that monitors changes in the table doesn't get updated.

```
@Query('DELETE FROM Car WHERE Id=:Id')
  Future<void> deleteById(int id);

@Query('SELECT * FROM Car')
  Stream<List<Car>?> getAllCars();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the generated code in the `DB.g.dart` file does not notify the `changeListener` if you attempt to insert, modify or delete a record using SQL query statements.
Thus, you should only use the `@insert/update/delete` methods for now, at least for version `floor: ^1.2.0`

Or, you can edit the `DB.g.dart` by adding `changeListener.add('entity_name');` in every generated method that does changes in order to receive updates on your Stream. However, upon every regeneration of the `DB.g.dart`, you must remember to rewrite those edits again.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example ? @Mena

Comment: @Mena please provide code.